# Computing the cardinality of a combinatorial set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Define two sets: $S_1$ and $S_2$ where we have that $a$ is an odd natural number and $b\in \mathbb{N}$,

$S_1 = \Big\{ \frac{2}{a},\frac{2}{a-2},\frac{2}{a-4},...,\frac{2}{a-(a-1)},$

$\frac{2+4}{a+2},\frac{2+4}{a},\frac{2+4}{a-2},...,\frac{2+4}{a-(a-1)},$

$\frac{2+8}{a+4},...,\frac{2+8}{a-2},...,\frac{2+8}{a-(a-1)},$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+4\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor},\frac{2+4\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},...,\frac{2+4\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{a-(a-1)},$

$\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor},\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},...,\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{a-(a-1),}$

$\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-4},...,\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{a-(a-1)}$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+4b}{a},\frac{2+4b}{a-2},...,\frac{2+4b}{a-(a-1)} \Big\}$

and

$S_2 = \Big\{ \frac{2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil}, \frac{2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-1},\frac{2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-2},...,\frac{2}{1}$

$\frac{2+2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+1},\frac{2+2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil},\frac{2+2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-1},...,\frac{2+2}{1},$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)},\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2)},...,\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)}{1}$

$\frac{2+2\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor},...,\frac{2+2\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{1},$

$\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1},...,\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{1},$

$\frac{2+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},...,\frac{2+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{1}$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+2b}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-1},...,\frac{2+2b}{1} \Big\}$

The question is, how do I determine the cardinality of the intersection of these two sets i.e. how would I compute the value $|S_1 \cap S_2|$? Note that duplicates may appear within both sets such as $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$ etc. Therefore we must make sure that for each fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ we have $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$. I am aware of the existence of https://oeis.org/A018805, but not entirely sure if that identity would be useful here.

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to descrive these two sets ins a simpler way: as they are written it's hard to read.

Comment: I have tried for a long time and I am trying to find a way. I will edit it here if I can find one.

Comment: A member of $S_2$ is part of $S_1$ if and only if it's most in it's lowest term $n/m$ where $gcd(n,m)=1$, both $n$ and $m$ are odd. I don't know if this is sufficient or you need a more explicit formula.

Comment: If you could provide a more explicit formula that could be useful!