# How to simplify this combinatorial formula and solve the cardinality of the intersection?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Define two sets: $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ where we have that $a$ is  odd (i.e. $a=2n+1$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$)  and $b\in \mathbb{N}$,

$\Sigma_1 = \Big\{ \frac{2}{a},\frac{2}{a-2},\frac{2}{a-4},...,\frac{2}{a-(a-1)},$

$\frac{2+4}{a+2},\frac{2+4}{a},\frac{2+4}{a-2},...,\frac{2+4}{a-(a-1)},$

$\frac{2+8}{a+4},...,\frac{2+8}{a-2},...,\frac{2+8}{a-(a-1)},$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+4\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor},\frac{2+4\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},...,\frac{2+4\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{a-(a-1)},$

$\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor},\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},...,\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{a-(a-1),}$

$\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{a+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-4},...,\frac{2+4(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{a-(a-1)}$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+4b}{a},\frac{2+4b}{a-2},...,\frac{2+4b}{a-(a-1)} \Big\}$

and

$\Sigma_2 = \Big\{ \frac{2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil}, \frac{2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-1},\frac{2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-2},...,\frac{2}{1}$

$\frac{2+2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+1},\frac{2+2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil},\frac{2+2}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-1},...,\frac{2+2}{1},$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)},\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2)},...,\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1)}{1}$

$\frac{2+2\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor},...,\frac{2+2\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor}{1},$

$\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-1},...,\frac{2+2(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+1)}{1},$

$\frac{2+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil+\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor-2},...,\frac{2+(\lfloor\frac{b}{2}\rfloor+2)}{1}$

$\vdots$

$\frac{2+2b}{\lceil\frac{a}{2}\rceil-1},...,\frac{2+2b}{1} \Big\}$

The question is, how do I determine the cardinality of the intersection of these two sets i.e. how would I compute the value $|\Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2|$? Note that duplicates may appear within both sets such as $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{4}{8}$ etc. Therefore we must make sure that for each fraction $\frac{n}{m}$ we have $\text{gcd}(n,m)=1$. I am aware of the existence of https://oeis.org/A018805, which really might help here. Unfortunately I struggle simplifying the formulas of $\Sigma_i$'s to simpler forms. My question is if these expressions may be simplified in any way or there is a way of finding the cardinality of $|\Sigma_1 \cap \Sigma_2|$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing the cardinality of a combinatorial set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4079213/computing-the-cardinality-of-a-combinatorial-set)

Comment: Please don't duplicate your questions. This violates site rules.